# Unification problem with HOL-style alpha-conversion in Coq (matching the equality)

Tags: coq, hol

I am experimenting with possibility of embedding of HOL4 proofs in Coq.

In HOL it is possible to give definition like

```
fun ALPHA t1 t2 = TRANS (REFL t1) (REFL t2)
```

Is it possible to somehow define this function in Coq in similar way? My attempt fails on the last line due to

```
The term "REFL t2" has type "t2 == t2"
while it is expected to have type "t1 == ?t3" (cannot unify 
"t2" and "t1").
```

The code:

```
Axiom EQ : forall {aa:Type}, aa -> aa -> Prop.
Notation " x == y " := (@EQ _ x y)  (at level 80).
Axiom REFL : forall {aa:Type} (a:aa), a == a.
Axiom TRANS :forall {T:Type}{t1 t2 t3:T},
 (t1 == t2) -> (t2 == t3) -> (t1 == t3).
Definition ALPHA t1 t2 := TRANS (REFL t1) (REFL t2).
```

ADDED:
Maybe there is a method of defining ALPHA such that we can assume that t1=t2? (I mean indeed, in Coq's standard sense of equality). I cann add assumption (H:t1=t2), but then I need to have matching somehow. How to do the matching with equality?

```
Definition ALPHA (t1 t2:T) (H:t1=t2) : t1==t2 :=
match H with
| eq_refl _ => TRANS (REFL t1) (REFL t2)
end
. (*fails*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you say more about how this definition is supposed to work in HOL?  If I'm guessing correctly, `ALPHA` is supposed to be a thing that fails to typecheck if its arguments are not alpha-convertible?  In Coq, you can use

```
Notation ALPHA t1 t2 := (TRANS (REFL t1) (REFL t2)).
```

You could also do

```
Notation ALPHA t1 t2 := (REFL t1 : t1 == t2).
```

or

```
Notation ALPHA t1 t2 := (eq_refl : t1 = t2).
```

Then you can write things like `Check ALPHA foo bar` to see if two things are convertible.  But I don't think this will be useful in most situations.  If you're looking for tactic programming, perhaps you're looking for the `unify` tactic or the `constr_eq` tactic?

Alternatively, if you want your `match` statement to work, you can write

```
Definition ALPHA {T:Type} (t1 t2 : T) (H : t1 = t2) : t1 == t2 :=
  match H with eq_refl => REFL _ end.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a unification problem, it really is a typing problem.
`REFL t1` has type `t1 == t1` and `REFL t2` has type `t2 == t2` as the error message is telling you. Transitivity would only work if somehow `t1` and `t2` were the same, but this is a priori not the case.

Perhaps what you wrote is not what you think you wrote.
If we were using only `t1`, then `TRANS (REFL t1) (REFL t1)` has type `t1 == t1`. Were you expecting `ALPHA t1 t2` to have type `t1 == t2`?
If it is the case, then your `EQ` relation would be total.

Comment: Maybe there is a method of defining ALPHA such that we can assume that t1=t2? (I mean indeed, in Coq's standard sense of equality). I cann add assumption (H:t1=t2), but then I need to have matching somehow.

Comment: What is `ALPHA` supposed to be? If you want to inject `x = y` into `x == y` there are easier ways.